# Unable to serialize property of 'records' on type common.api.soap.wsdl.QueryResult

Tags: query

I have bellow query

```
SELECT
        HOUR_IN_DAY(NextFireTime) Id, COUNT(Id) i
FROM CronTrigger
GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(NextFireTime)
```

which gives me the following error

```
Unable to serialize property of 'records' on type common.api.soap.wsdl.QueryResult
```

On the other hand following queries works just fine

```
SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) FROM Contact
GROUP BY AccountId
```

```
SELECT
        HOUR_IN_DAY(NextFireTime) asd, COUNT(Id) i
FROM CronTrigger
GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(NextFireTime)
```

So I assume that something weird is going on with the `CronTrigger` object and with the `Id` alias, as when I rename the `Id` it suddenly works as expected.

I know a workaround for this but was just curious if someone knows what is going on?

Comment: You seem to be trying to alias an aggregate function as Id, which I suggest is expected to identify a Lookup field/record identifier in query results. What if you rename it?

Comment: if i rename it it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue is hidden somewhere inside the serialization methods. Therefore, we are unable to properly localize it.

The query works when the `Id` alias is not used. But that mean that this approach cannot be used to initialize `Map` of `AgregateResults` by the aliased field.